# Issues with pivot table with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with creating pivot table in Laravel. That's the first time I'm using it, and after searching on Internet, I can't manage to fix my issue.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'champions_teams.teams_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `champions`.*, `champions_teams`.`teams_id` as `pivot_teams_id`, `champions_teams`.`champions_id` as `pivot_champions_id`, `champions_teams`.`champion_id` as `pivot_champion_id` from `champions` inner join `champions_teams` on `champions`.`id` = `champions_teams`.`champions_id` where `champions_teams`.`teams_id` = 1) (View: C:\laragon\www\proyecto-web\resources\views\teams\teamIndex.blade.php)
```

Following, the way I created my classes "Champions" and "Teams", with my pivot table migration.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\softDeletes;

class Teams extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'teams';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','name','rank','region'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function champions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Champions::class)->withPivot('champion_id');
    }

    public function files(){
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'model');
    }

    public function setNameAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['name'] = strtoupper($value);
    }

    public function getTeamsNameAttribute(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Champions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'champions';
    protected $fillable = ['name','health_points','type','role'];

    public function teams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teams::class)->withPivot('team_id');;
    }

    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Items::class, 'champion_id');
    }

}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class PivotTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('champions_teams', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('champion_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id');

            $table->foreign('champion_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('champions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('team_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('teams')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help ! You can also access the whole code right here : https://github.com/ValentinDelpy/proyecto-web

Comment: Remove the withPivot('team_id') and withPivot('champion_id'); from yours belongsToMany relationships

Comment: Still didn't change my issue. Might come from the collision as said by Piotrek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
Since you are not following the name conventions which Laravel expects, you should customize the name of the joining table, the column names of the keys on the table by passing additional arguments to the `belongsToMany` method. The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

```
class Champions extends Model
{

    public function teams(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Teams::class, 'champions_teams', 'team_id', 'champion_id');
    }

}

class Teams extends Model
{
    public function champions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Champions::class, 'champions_teams', 'champion_id', 'team_id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems You have collision with teams and team.

You model is named `Teams` (should be `Team`).

Checkout how to make many to many relations propely:

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Is there an easy way to change it in the whole project ? Attempting to do it manually, just generating more issues

Answer (score 0):

Probably Laravel is generating the id from the Model name, so if the Project is brand new, just change it, otherwise, you have to declare the foreign keys name in the `belogsToMany` function (check https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_belongsToMany).

Also keep in mind that the `witPivot` function is to let Laravel know the existence of other fields more than the only 2 foreign keys, not the foreign keys themself (check https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_withPivot)